# post back selected radio button in adaptive card in .NET

Tags: .net, bots, botframework, chatbot, adaptive-cards

I am using .NET SDK for adaptive cards which is having radio buttons and **submit** action.

I want to get selected radio button as post back question like **imBack** in **Herocards**.

**Is there any way to get button selected value as post back question in adaptive cards?**

Comment: What bot framework channel is receiving your card and sending the imBack back?

Comment: right now i am using bot emulator for testing and i want to show radio button selected value as a user asked question on Action.Submit in adaptive cards.